# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Performance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server, sp1

I've noticed since installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 that I'm having huge performance issues. It will randomly freeze up on me quite a bit.

I had no performance issues with Visual Studio 2010 before the upgrade. The only add-on I have running is ReSharper.

I'm wondering if anyone else is experiencing performance issues? If so have you found a way to fix them?

Comment: VS2010 SP1 with Resharper on my PC too. Haven't seen any performance changes since I installed the SP.

Comment: I have VS2010 SP1 and Resharper plus a few other extensions and the performance is still as slow as ever :) Not noticed any freeze ups though.

Comment: It also comes with quite a few bugs. I hope SP2 is better.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing as you are Mark. Don't know the solution yet... Did you try removing Resharper to see if it helps? I will and let you know.

Comment: @Gustavo So far the one thing that has helped most has been disabling the Microsoft Productivity Power Tools, the seem to have been causing most of the slowness.

Comment: Mark, I did the same and it seems to have helped. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a programming tool (IDE) and would belong on Stack Overflow, but is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small heads up about SP1:

- If you have SQL Server Management Studio installed on the same machine, **don't** install SP1 just yet.  You will lose all intellisense functionality.  This is a major bug that must of slipped through.

In terms of performance, I haven't really noticed much of a difference.

Comment: Just checked to see if it were true and what do you know? It is so! Oh my, don't they test things any longer? With ASP.NET MVC 3 you can't officially add a project to an existing solution because it makes Visual Studio crash. It's become really ugly last years.

Comment: The intellisense in SQL Server Management Studio can be refreshed with Control-Alt-R.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems like disabling the Productivity Power Tools is the key to solve this problem, at least to help with slowness. At least it worked out for me. Thanks Mark for your question/answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot more crashes since installing IronPython, but the main key to crashing appears to involve solutions with projects in 2 or more programming languages. I won't get crashes in C#-only solutions, nor VB-only solutions, but only in the ones with both (and more!) languages. It might also be that those solutions have a lot more projects.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to use VS 2010 only once, and I am glad we are not upgrading to it for my project. We have to shut down all other applications before we start it. Even then it can take a good 10 minutes to load. We will need the latest PC config with lots of RAM and the latest OS to get it any faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember reading that in SP1 they switch off hardware gfx acceleration. You can re-enable it in the settings somewhere. Apparently for some people it was causing problems so they disable it by default.

I've got it installed on a few machines here and I haven't noticed it running slower, but I've got a dozen plug ins, extensions and so forth enabled as well, so it was never particularly quick...